# Is it possible to restore apps/data from 4.2.1 to 4.4.4?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, 4.4-kitkat, backup, restore, titanium-backup

I'm prepping to upgrade from PA 4.2.1 to CarbonROM 4.4.4 (VZW Galaxy Nexus). I'd prefer using TB to restore my selected apps + data I've had running on 4.2.1, but understand that this is a big jump between Android OSes.

Is there any way to do this? If not both, then what about just the apps?

Answer (score 1):

Generally this shouldn't be a problem. The only problem with restoring between different Android versions is when you backup and restore the system apps' data from a different version. If you only restore the apps you installed and their data, you'll be OK in most cases.

A few apps might have different versions of the app for different Android versions, so those apps might not work properly because you've restored the data from a different version of the app. This is unusual, though, so you'll probably find that all your apps work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

By default all the apps are forward compatible(moving apps from a previous version say 4.0 to 4.4.4 in this case) because there are only new API additions to the existing ones .

As mentioned by @Dan In Rare cases you may find the app not compatible with the latest version only because an API is removed possibly due to some issues.

Still if the app is not compatible an update is released by the developer's in order to make sure the App compatibility stays  even with the future versions of Android.

**Note**:- Android applications are not necessarily backward compatible(moving back from v4.4.2(Kit-Kat) to 4.1(Jelly bean) or even 2.3(Ginger bread)) due to lack of supporting API's in the present which lack in the previous versions.

So you can go ahead with your restoration provided there's a backup ready for any unwanted issue.

Answer (score -1):

I have experienced so very many problems with 4.4.4 which really SUX!!! It has been such a waste of time and effort after getting 4.4.4

> > > I sure do miss being able to just plug in the OTG to my Moto G XT1034 2298 and a flash drive to dump most any file I wanted into the flash drive. It was so very quick and easy. <<<

Although I found the fastest way to transfer pics and files is with a free app from GooglePlay that is called ""SEND ANYWHERE"" It works a whole lot better than anything else I've tried... But requires a great deal of patience and time.

- One of my biggest REGRETS was the moment I "upgraded" to the Android 4.4.4 OS!!!

Please be kind to yourself...  DON'T  Subject Yourself to all the NIGHTMARES of 4.4.4